# Deploy app to a physical iPhone with connected Mac build host

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

i'm trying to debug an app on my iPhone connected to my windows 10 pc via usb. I have successfully connected VS for Windows (Version 17.3.6) to my build host (Mac in Cloud). I can also debug my app with the "Remote Simulator to Windows" or via Hot Restart. All this works.
But i'm not able to deploy the app for debugging on my physical device, which is build on the mac build host.

I tried disabling Hot Restart, because i have a build host and Hot Restart is without a build host. But if i disable Hot Restart the connected device disappears from die VS device list. Only remote device and the simulators are visible.

I expect, that VS uses die build host to build the app and delploy it to the connected device. Is this not possible or i miss something?

Thx

Comment: IMHO, this is an important question, and it is not obvious how to get this to work these days. I've worked with Xamarin for years, but due to multiple changes Apple made over the past twelve months, the only way I am able to configure a physical iOS device is by physically attaching it to a local Mac, and using Xcode to download (provision?) to the iOS device. If the build Mac is not local, I don't see how to involve Xcode in the device provisioning process. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: The certificates to sign the app and the profiles are in this folder: C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Local\Xamarin\iOS\Provisioning. The provisioning profile file must be copy to the device to tell the device that an app with a specific signing key is trusted. VS for Windows can also copy the profile file. Or you can copy the provisioning file via itunes for windows.

Comment: *"copy the provisioning file via itunes for windows"* - that is the piece I needed to know; thanks. For your situation, if you disable Hot Restart, then restart PC (so that both VS and ADB get reinitialized), THEN plug in the phone, it still never appears? Maybe switch to Android project, then back to iOS project? Trying to think how to get VS to "look again" for attached iOS devices.

Comment: Tested all of this. Also tried latest VS Preview. But the Phone disappeard if Hot Restart is disabled and connection to mac build host is establisht

Answer (score 0):

You said"I can also debug my app with the "Remote Simulator to Windows" or via Hot Restart." it means that you can debug the app via simulator but not a physical device, right? According to the documentation [Xamarin Hot Restart - Xamarin | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart), using Hot Restart can only connect to physical devices (not sumulators), and only supports Xamarin.Forms projects(There is a Xamarin.iOS in this thread).

In addition, you could if your apple developer account is an enterprise account or an individual account. [Creating API Keys for App Store Connect API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/creating_api_keys_for_app_store_connect_api) is required when using Individual account for Hot Restart.

If you are testing on a physical device, you should configure the device first. You can configure it by creating a development certificate and provisioning profile through [Automatic Provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?tabs=macos) or [Manual provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/manual-provisioning?tabs=macos). If your iPhone version is iOS16 and above, you also should turn on developer mode in your phone.

For more details you can refer to this document:[Device provisioning | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/)

Comment: I can debug the app via simulator AND via Hot Restart (physical device), but not a physical device without Hot Restart. Hot Restart is cool, but has a few limitations. We have an enterprise account. On my device developer mode is activated and we use manual provisioning, because auto works only with wildcard.

Comment: Based on what Saftpresse99 says, they have done all of the above. Is there any way to tell VS to "search again" for attached devices?